# How would you make a countdown timer / progress bar based on relative times?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time

I'm trying to make a relative countdown timer for the day (user input - defaults 8am to 6pm):

```php
$mb_time_start      = strtotime( 'today 0800' );
$mb_time_end        = strtotime( 'today 1800' );
$mb_time_elapsed    = ( $mb_time_end - $mb_time_start );
```

```js
function mb_countdown_timer() {

    var mb_time_start   = <?= $mb_time_start; ?>,
        mb_time_end     = <?= $mb_time_end; ?>,
        mb_time_now     = new Date(),

        mb_time_today   = <?= $mb_time_end; ?>,
        mb_time_elapsed = mb_time_now - mb_time_start,

        mb_percent      = ( ( mb_time_elapsed / mb_time_today )  );

        console.log( mb_percent );
}
```

However at the moment the log is coming up as `998.9775919881246` which is incorrect - even for 7pm while writing this.

My intention after I can get the above is to have the calculation of 30 minute intervals between `start` to `end` -> 0800 to 1800 = 10h * 2 = 20

```
8am               12pm                                      6pm
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then from `mb_countdown_timer()` fill the progress bar:

```
8am                    12pm                                      6pm
------------------------------------------------------------------
| * | * | * | * | * |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | 
------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, needed to set the timezone - that was issue one! Secondly, I misinterpreted the JS vs PHP outputs, which resulted in the JS being in milliseconds while PHP was seconds - so had to convert milliseconds to seconds. For the seconds part I had the question here: [How would you loop every 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59610890/1086990) where I outputted the timer bar on top.

```php
date_default_timezone_set( get_option('timezone_string') ); // Australia/Melbourne` 
$mb_time_start      = strtotime( 'today 0800' );
$mb_time_end        = strtotime( 'today 1800' );
$mb_time_total      = ( $mb_time_end - $mb_time_start ); // 36000
```

```js
function mb_countdown_timer() {

    // get the start time
    var mb_time_start = <?= $mb_time_start; ?>,

    // get the end time
        mb_time_end   = <?= $mb_time_end; ?>,

    // get the seconds total (end - start)
        mb_time_total = <?= $mb_time_total; ?>,

    // get the time now
        mb_time_now = new Date(),

    // milliseconds to seconds
        mb_time_now = Math.floor( mb_time_now / 1000 ),

    // elapsed time from start time
        mb_time_elapsed = mb_time_now - mb_time_start,

    // convert to percentage
        mb_time_percent     = ( ( mb_time_elapsed / mb_time_total ) * 100 ),

    // check the % is neither >100 or <0
        mb_time_percent     = ( (mb_time_percent > 100 || mb_time_percent < 0) ? 0 : mb_time_percent );

    // add the positioning via css
    $(".mb-marker").css("left", mb_time_percent + "%");

    // run at 1 minute
    setTimeout(mb_countdown_timer, 1000 * 60);

}

// run continuously 
setInterval( mb_countdown_timer(), (1000 * 60) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if mb_percent      = ( ( mb_time_elapsed / mb_time_today )  ); is correct. Shouldn't mb_time_today be equal to mb_time_end- mb_start