# How would you loop every 30 minutes

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Trying to make a `for` loop that has the `HHMM` outputted in a `data-time` HTML field.

I currently have:

```php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 20; ++$i) {
    echo '<div class="mb-timer-hour"><div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="0830"></div></div>';
}
```

Except this outputs `data-time="0830"` every time.

I then tried `$h = 30; $h + 30` but this then goes: `0800, 0830, 0860, 0890, ...`

Is it possible to loop `0800, 0830, 0900, 0930, ...`?

The start time and end times are user variables which is why I haven't hard coded an array.

The output I was hoping for was:

```php
<div class="mb-timer-hour"><div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="0830"></div></div>
<div class="mb-timer-hour"><div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="0930"></div></div>
<div class="mb-timer-hour"><div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="1030"></div></div>
...
<div class="mb-timer-hour"><div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="1730"></div></div>
```

Comment: make a funcion to run your code, create a clock, run funcion every(your_time) inside the clock, reset time after run funcion, start again

Comment: Does this answer your question? [creating a loop for time incremented by 15 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949035/creating-a-loop-for-time-incremented-by-15-minutes)

Comment: @DevsiOdedra it’s similar but not the answer i was after. the loop i have above is to output n number of divs, where the time part is every half hour. when i try looping two fors i end up with all the times per div block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTime objects and always add 30 minutes (or 60 minutes) until the end time is reached. The format method is used in the loop to output the times.

```
$start = '0830';
$end = '1230';
$date_end = date_create($end);

for($date = date_create($start);$date <= $date_end; $date->modify('+30 Minutes')){

  echo '<div class="mb-timer-hour"><div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="'.$date->format('Hi').'"></div></div>';
}
```

The HTML output in a loop is not nice. I took it from the question. If the test runs in the browser, the page source text must be viewed for the result.

Comment: Thank you for that - actually something very similar to what I ended up doing in my work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637728/1086990 but yours is a bit more elegant

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up solving this was with the following code:

```php
$mb_timer_start = strtotime( 'today 0800' );
$mb_timer_end = strtotime( 'today 1800' );
```

```html
<div class="mbcontainer mb-timer">
    <div class="mb-timer-container">

        <!-- this is related to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59637684/1086990 -->
        <div class="mb-marker"></div>

        <?php
            // loop through start H until end H
            for( $i = date('H', $mb_timer_start); $i < date('H', $mb_timer_end); ++$i ) {
                echo '<div class="mb-timer-hour" style="width:calc(100% / ' . $mb_timer_diff . ');" data-time="' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '00">';
                    echo '<div class="mb-timer-half" data-time="' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) . '30"></div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

This code changed with the addition of the hour `data-time` too but the looping was still the question.